# MediaPlayer, not playing music on onResume() after having returned from an activity

Tags: android

On the MainActivity, I play a background music using MediaPlayer.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Music.playBGmusic(this, R.raw.main_music);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      if ( ! Music.isPlaying(this) )
      {
          Music.playBGmusic(this, R.raw.main_music);
      }
}
```

In Music.java:

```
public class Music {
   private static MediaPlayer mMainSound = null;
   public static boolean isPlaying(Context context)
   {
       if ( mMainSound != null )
       {
           return mMainSound.isPlaying();
       }
       return false;
   }

   public static void playBGmusic(Context context, int resource)
   {
       if ( mMainSound != null ) mMainSound.release();
       mMainSound = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
       mMainSound.setLooping(true);
       mMainSound.start();
   }

   public static void stopBGmusic(Context context) {
       if (mMainSound != null) {
           mMainSound.stop();
           mMainSound.release();
           mMainSound = null;
       }
   }
}
```

where `mMainSound` is a MediaPlayer object. There is a button on my MainActivity, and when it's clicked, it creates an intent, and `startActivity` that intent. This new activity calls `playBGmusic` with **another sound**. Now when that new activity calls `stopBGmusic()` and  `finish()` to return to MainActivity, `onResume()` of MainActivity is called as expected, and it's supposed to play `main_music` in the background. What actually happens is that I could only hear less than a second of the music, and it gets cut off. I tried with `prepare()` before starting MediaPlayer, but still that doesn't solve the problem. It will be very much appreciated if anyone could clarify this issue for me..

Maybe I should also mention where `finish()` is called in the new activity, although I'm not sure if that's of any importance..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            showDialog(1);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}  

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) { //id is ignored
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.return_home)
           .setCancelable(true)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: is Music a service or simple class? Since you are playing background I am assuming it is a service.

Comment: Could you please post the top part of the class names so we can see what you are using for interfaces and supers?

Comment: Yeah it's just a simple class.. I edited my code just to show. I will have to change it, i guess

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that onResume will always be called after onCreate so you only need to set the media player to play in onResume.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I could have just put: else { Music.playBGmusic(this, R.raw.main_music); } in onResume(). Although that doesn't explain why it gets cut off.

Comment: So the music is played correctly. As it was called in onResume(). It just gets cut off after few milliseconds.

Comment: In my case same behaviour is occuring and I observed onCompletion of media player was getting call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really bind a service to control the MediaPlayer, not have your main activity control it. Instead it should control the service via you binding the service it to your app.

To put it simply(assuming you want to continuously play music even upon exiting you app):

When your are playing music you want to run it in the background and have your app control (start/stop/pause)  states of your mediaplayer. When you create the media player you play from the background instead of the foreground. This allows you to continuously play music while the user has your service running.

Communication could be setup using PendingIntent to communicate with your service, through capturing you specific intent filters. I'd recommend go to the Google dev site and do some of the tutorials and try to learn how Intents, intent-filter/actions, and services and also learn the lifecycle of activities and services.

To do this properly your should allocate some time to research/experiment and learn about android.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more? Like what is actually the problem, and how that could solve it.. I'm sorry but I'm new to android.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't keep playing the music when the app is closed, but I'll look into the service. What I need to do is that, when switching from one activity to another, I need to play a *different* music. The problem was that somehow this music got cut off when playBGmusic() was called in onResume()

Comment: Hey actually that code is just a snippet of what I actually have, and it turned out that stopBGmusic() and my logic in onResume() were the problems. I kinda forgot what I did.. but I basically cleaned up and it works now. Thank you for your help!